How can I make a fixed element that interacts with other elements in CSS?
I want to place an image towards the bottom of the page, let’s say around top: 70%. No matter how many elements are added above it, the image should not be affected by them. The image should only start moving further down the page when elements reach it, as if it’s set in place by default.
ex :


What have you tried ?

The problem is that when we set it to position: fixed, it remains fixed. (of course stay fixed :))

Please share [mre] such as related CSS and HTML. This sounds like you shouldn't use fixed and without more code it's hard to tell what solution fits your need. We can't even know how the size of your container is controlled.

For something to always stay on the bottom, one approach with flexbox is to have a wrapper div that goes from the top of the screen to however far you want it to go (allowing for it to go further if there is more content to be shown). Then give that div two div children, one for the top and another for the bottom. Space the divs with space-between on the div wrapper and make sure the flex-direction property is set to column so the content flows from top to bottom and then the bottom content div will always be at the bottom of the div wrapper. See an example implementation below.


const pCountRange = document.getElementById("p-count");
const pDiv = document.getElementById("top");
pCountRange.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let pCount = pCountRange.value;
  while (pDiv.firstChild) {
    pDiv.removeChild(pDiv.lastChild);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < pCount; i++) {
    let p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = "Always on the top!";
    pDiv.appendChild(p);
  }
});
#wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 5px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="range" id="p-count" name="p-count" min="1" max="11" value="3">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
      <p>Always on the top!</p>
      <p>Always on the top!</p>
      <p>Always on the top!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
      <p>I'm always at the bottom.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



